# JQuery's $("*", document) returns only one item: html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a page with two frames on it, and I have managed to respond to reloads of one of these frames.  In the handler for the reload, I am trying to select an item on the newly loaded frame using jQuery, like so:

```
  $("frame[name=WorkArea]").on("load", function () {
    console.log("Reloaded work area."); //this works fine
    alert($("tr.hdr", "frame[name=WorkArea]").html());
  });
```

The alert box says "undefined."  When I experiment at console to 'select everything',

```
$("*", "frame[Name=WorkArea]")
```

only one item is listed: the raw html of the frame.

So basically I can't select anything within the frame.  It looks like the DOM is not yet constructed for the HTML contents of the frame (?)  What am I missing?

PS Not sure this is relevant, but it's within an injected content script for a Chrome extension.

Comment: for security reazons javascript cannot access to another host

Comment: @xzegga confused...why can I see the html then?  Also, the domain is the same for the outer page and inner frames.

Comment: try selecting iframe by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("frame[name=WorkArea]").on("load", function () {
   console.log("Reloaded work area."); //this works fine
   alert($(this).contents().find('tr.hdr').html()); // use this and find() here
});
```

Comment: I'm getting what seem to be the same results as before: $(this).find('*') returns empty brackets (or undefined when 'html()' added); $(this) shows in console as a frame containing a document containing HTML.  Could this be something do with running the script from a Chrome Extension content script?

Comment: Try to use `contents()` before `find()` see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`.find()`** in jquery

```
$("*").find("frame[name=WorkArea]").html();
```

or

```
 $(document).find("frame[name=WorkArea]").html();
```